# matplotlib 'FigureCanvasQTAgg' object has no attribute 'set_cursor'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm getting this error when trying to set the mouse icon like so:

```
fig.canvas.set_cursor(Cursors.POINTER) # or something like that
```

I assume this is because the set_cursor method is missing from the backend? I'm working with a Qt applicaion that embedds matplotlib plots. Is there any way to fix this?

I tried setting the backend with matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg") because apparently that solved similar problems for other people but it didn't work.

Comment: The Qt backend figure is a standard QWidget, you could use [`setCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop) with a [Qt.CursorShape](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CursorShape-enum). In any case, provide a valid [mre] ("something like that" is quite vague).